# syntactically sweetening swift callbacks from c

Tags: c, swift, swift2, ffi

I'm learning Swift. I've got a C interface calling back into Swift-2 code:

```
let inputProc: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>, UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, UInt32, UInt32, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus = {
    (inRefCon, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, ioData) in

    // do things here

    return noErr
}
```

It works, but it's hard to look at and my process for writing this kind of code is very awkward: I copy the declaration of the callback, add `= { (a, b, c, d, e) in` then I replace the `a, b, c`s in the tuple with better names as I *discover* their types.

Is there any way I can move the callback parameter names closer to their types?
Say by writing `let inputProc = @convention(c) (inRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, ...)` and letting type inference sort it out? My attempts at guessing the syntax have failed.

[Dan Beaulieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1664443/dan-beaulieu) made the great suggestion of using a `typealias`. Luckily one exists already, and my code becomes much easier to look at:

```
let inputProc: AURenderCallback = {
    (inRefCon, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, ioData) in

    return noErr
}
```

But now the argument types are more mysterious than ever (although only an option-click away).  I'm beginning to suspect that I can't actually have a c-callback with nice, localised argument declarations, which would make  `typealias` the best solution.

Comment: I'm sure you've already considered this but would "typealias" get you anywhere?

Comment: I had not and it's a big improvement! I was hoping to get more obvious argument types (not less) but I think this is probably the best I'm going to get. Why don't you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sweet, Your new version looks much cleaner!